# Flex mobile TextInput events

Tags: apache-flex

I can't seem to get any events to fire from a TextInput control in a Flex mobile app.

```
<s:TextInput id="testInput" valueCommit="textInputHandler(event)" 
             touchEnd="textInputHandler(event)" 
             touchBegin="textInputHandler(event)"
             touchOut="textInputHandler(event)" 
             click="textInputHandler(event)"
             />
```

I originally needed only the ValueCommit event but I can't get any of the events listed in the example above to fire .

I've tried on the Flash Builder device simulator and on an actual Android and iPad device with no luck.

Answer (score 0):

So TextInput.textDisplay is a StyleableStageText for mobile (as opposed to RichEditableText otherwise).  StyleableStageText doesn't dispatch the ValueCommit event.  I suppose you could skin it to use RichEditableText but you'd lose the mobile optimizations.

I ended up using the FocusOut event for what I needed.